How to load the pre-trained model?
I am running this model from GitHub, and I have not understood how and where to run step 2 and 3.
2. Load the pre-trained model:
model = network.modeling.dict[MODEL_NAME](num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, output_stride=OUTPUT_STRIDE)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH_TO_PTH)["model_state"])

3. Visualize segmentation outputs:
outputs = model(images)
preds = outputs.max(1)[1].detach().cpu().numpy()
colorized_preds = val_dst.decode_target(preds).astype("uint8")
# To RGB images, (N, H, W, 3), ranged 0~255, numpy array

# Do whatever you like here with the colorized segmentation maps 
colorized_preds = Image.fromarray(colorized_preds[0]) # to PIL Image

I have download the pre-trained models.

Take a look at the predict.py file as an example on how to use the model.
